# Apache Flink: No execution.target specified in your configuration file

Tags: gradle, apache-flink

I wrote a program with Flink framework which has a custom data source. The custom data source listens over a web socket to a crypto currency ticker price stream. The main method looks like this:

```java
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            StreamExecutionEnvironment streamExecutionEnvironment = new StreamExecutionEnvironment();
            DataStream<TickerPrice> highestBidDataStream = streamExecutionEnvironment
                    .addSource(new GdaxSourceFunction())
                    .keyBy((tickerPrice) -> {
                return tickerPrice.getExchange() + "_" + tickerPrice.getFromCurrency() + "_" + tickerPrice.getToCurrency();
            }).window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(1))).maxBy("highestBid");
    
            highestBidDataStream.print();
            streamExecutionEnvironment.execute("Gdax Highest bid window calculator");
        }
    }
```

I run the program in a local cluster this way:

```sh
    ./start-cluster.sh
    ./flink run --target local /path/to/Projects/CryptoFlink/build/libs/CryptoFlink-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I build it with this build.gradle which is almost an exact copy from [apache flink quickstart](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/project-configuration.html#maven-quickstart):

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter() // this applies only to the Gradle 'Shadow' plugin
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:2.0.4'
        }
    }
    
    plugins {
        id 'java'
        id 'application'
        id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '6.1.0'
    }
    
    // artifact properties
    group = 'com.cryptoflink'
    version = '0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    mainClassName = 'com.cryptoflink.main.Main'
    description = """Cryptocurrency Flink Program"""
    
    ext {
        javaVersion = '1.8'
        flinkVersion = '1.11.2'
        scalaBinaryVersion = '2.12'
        slf4jVersion = '1.7.15'
        log4jVersion = '2.12.1'
    }
    
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
    
    configurations {
        flinkShadowJar // dependencies which go into the shadowJar
    
        // always exclude these (also from transitive dependencies) since they are provided by Flink
        flinkShadowJar.exclude group: 'org.apache.flink', module: 'force-shading'
        flinkShadowJar.exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'jsr305'
        flinkShadowJar.exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
        flinkShadowJar.exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j'
    }
    
    def flinkVersion = '1.11.2'
    dependencies {
    
        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    
        flinkShadowJar 'javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:1.1'
    
        flinkShadowJar 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.1'
        flinkShadowJar group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.9.4'
        flinkShadowJar group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.9.4'
        flinkShadowJar group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-hibernate5', version: '2.9.4'
    
        compile "org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java_${scalaBinaryVersion}:${flinkVersion}"
    
        flinkShadowJar 'org.glassfish.tyrus:tyrus-server:1.12'
        flinkShadowJar 'org.glassfish.tyrus:tyrus-container-grizzly-server:1.12'
    
        compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:${log4jVersion}"
        compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:${log4jVersion}"
        compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:${log4jVersion}"
        compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:${slf4jVersion}"
    }
    
    sourceSets {
        main.compileClasspath += configurations.flinkShadowJar
        main.runtimeClasspath += configurations.flinkShadowJar
        test.compileClasspath += configurations.flinkShadowJar
        test.runtimeClasspath += configurations.flinkShadowJar
    
        javadoc.classpath += configurations.flinkShadowJar
    }
    
    run.classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    
    jar {
        manifest {
            attributes 'Built-By': System.getProperty('user.name'),
                    'Build-Jdk': System.getProperty('java.version')
        }
    }
    
    shadowJar {
        configurations = [project.configurations.flinkShadowJar]
    }
```

But I always get this error:

```java
        org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: No execution.target specified in your configuration file.
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:302)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:198)
        at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:149)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:699)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:232)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:916)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:992)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:30)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:992)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: No execution.target specified in your configuration file.
        at org.apache.flink.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:75)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1798)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1711)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1697)
        at com.cryptoflink.main.Main.main(Main.java:26)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
```

The Flink tutorials do not mention any such configuration file that needs to be in the project for it to run. However, [one tutorial](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/deployment/cli.html) says "--target local" to the run command should set the execution.target to the local cluster. But this isn't working.

I have tried:

1. Adding execution.target to flink-1.11.2/conf/flink-conf.yaml
2. Specifying --target local, --target remote, in the run command.
3. Running the flink examples. These work, yet I can't tell by looking at the JAR what is the crucial difference between my JAR and the example JAR.
4. Adding main/resources/conf/flink-conf.yaml and main/resources/flink-conf.yaml with execution.target : local.

Versions:

JDK 1.8
Flink 1.11.2

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to access the StreamExecutionEnvironment instead of creating a new one:

```java
StreamExecutionEnvironment streamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
```

Thanks to Kostas Kloudas from the Flink email list for this solution.